# DBATools - Remove timestamp from Export-DBAScript -PATH

Tags: sql, file, path, timestamp, dbatools

Is it possible to remove the timestamp when `Export-DBAScript -PATH` is used? I would just like to use the Server Name and Date.

For example this is what I want to export:

```ps
Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance $ServerList| EXPORT-DBASCRIPT -PATH $FILENAME -Append
```

This is what my Output File is named (I would like to not have the timestamp):
[image: FileName with Timestamp]

Is this is possible, and if so how I would go by achieving this?

Comment: Use `-FilePath` parameter for exact file name

Comment: You should paste your code directly into question and not via image. Check the help on code formatting in the top-right corner of input field.

Comment: @astentx, when I use -FilePath, I have to specify the name, If I am exporting Jobs from multiple servers they are all in one file, I wanted to know if there is a way to change this default filename using -Path as it exports the script per a server. I just need to remove the Timestamp. Is it possible by using -Path?

Thanks for the heads up WRT to code pasting.